# Docker Swarm - Containers can ping between nodes, cannot communicate over TCP ports

Tags: networking, docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

I'm setting up a new Docker Swarm mode cluster on three Linux machines - all brand new installations.
All three machines have their firewalls and security modules (AppArmor) disabled and I could confirm they can communicate over ports `7946` (TCP and UDP) and `4789` (UDP).

For example, one of the stacks I'm bringing up:

```yml
...
  wikijs_db:
    image: postgres:11-alpine
    deploy:
      replicas: 1
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: ***
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ***
      POSTGRES_USER: ***
      HA_ACTIVE: 1
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - db_assets:/root/assets
  wikijs_wiki:
    image: requarks/wiki:2.5
    deploy:
      replicas: 1
    depends_on:
      - wikijs_db
    environment:
      DB_TYPE: postgres
      DB_HOST: wikijs_db
      DB_PORT: 5432
      DB_USER: ***
      DB_PASS: ***
      DB_NAME: ****
      HA_ACTIVE: 1
    volumes:
      - "/etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro"
      - data:/backup/data
      - assets:/root/assets
...
```

When creating a cluster, containers are spread out between the nodes - and can communicate with `ping`, as well as resolve their hostnames:

```
/wiki $ ping wikijs_db
PING wikijs_db (10.0.1.4): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 10.0.1.4: seq=0 ttl=42 time=0.113 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.1.4: seq=1 ttl=42 time=0.134 ms
```

However containers cannot communicate over TCP:

```
/wiki $ nc -vz wikijs_db 5432


nc: wikijs_db (10.0.1.4:5432): Operation timed out
```

This occurs only between nodes in the swarm.

I've tried recreating the swarm, reinstalling the operating systems, running different containers as well as assigning the default network a predefined subnet, all with no success. I can't see any errors in the Docker daemon's log on any of the nodes, either.

I'd greatly appreciate help in solving this issue.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Solved by running `ethtool -K [interface] tx off` as suggested in this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66251422/docker-swarm-overlay-network-icmp-works-but-not-anything-else